# Simple Paint Program using p5.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, paint, p5.js

I have been working on creating a simple paint program using p5.js . So far I created my paint palette and I am able to draw on my canvas. I need help with changing palette colors using the mouseIsPressed method. I want to click on a color and then draw on my canvas. This is what I have so far.

```
function setup(){
createCanvas(500,500);
}

function draw() {
noStroke();
//red
fill(255,0,0);
rect(0,0,20,20);
//orange
fill(255,165,0);
rect(0,20,20,20);
//yellow
fill(255,255,0);
rect(0,40,20,20);
//green
fill(0,255,0);
rect(0,60,20,20);
//cyan
fill(0,255,255);
rect(0,80,20,20);
//blue
fill(0,0,255);
rect(0,100,20,20);
//magenta
fill(255,0,255);
rect(0,120,20,20);
//brown
fill(165,42,42);
rect(0,140,20,20);
//white
fill(255);
rect(0,160,20,20);
//black
fill(0);
rect(0,180,20,20);

if(mouseIsPressed ){
  if(mouseIsPressed && mouseX == 0 && mouseY == 0){
    strokeWeight(10);
    stroke(0);
    line(pmouseX,pmouseY,mouseX,mouseY);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```js
var selected;

function setup(){
createCanvas(500,500);
}

function draw() {
noStroke();
//red
fill(255,0,0);
rect(0,0,20,20);
//orange
fill(255,165,0);
rect(0,20,20,20);
//yellow
fill(255,255,0);
rect(0,40,20,20);
//green
fill(0,255,0);
rect(0,60,20,20);
//cyan
fill(0,255,255);
rect(0,80,20,20);
//blue
fill(0,0,255);
rect(0,100,20,20);
//magenta
fill(255,0,255);
rect(0,120,20,20);
//brown
fill(165,42,42);
rect(0,140,20,20);
//white
fill(255);
rect(0,160,20,20);
//black
fill(0);
rect(0,180,20,20);
}

function mousePressed (){
  if(collide(0, 0)){
    selected = "red";
  }else if(collide(0, 20)){
    selected = "orange";
  }else if(collide(0, 40)){
    selected = "yellow";
  }//and so on...
}

function collide ( x, y) {
//2d
if (mouseX >= x &&         // right of the left edge AND
    mouseX <= x + 20 &&    // left of the right edge AND
    mouseY >= y &&         // below the top AND
    mouseY <= y + 20) {    // above the bottom
        return true;
}
return false;
};
```

The collide function returns true when mouse is over certain rect, and false if its not. That way you can use `if (collide( **x and y coordinates of rect** )) {}` to do something, in this case define a variable. Hope this helps you, have a nice day.

Also note that the collide function takes the top-left corner x and y of the rectangle.

Uses of mousePressed https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mousePressed